# how to fill a table in jasper?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

i have a jasper report which has a table in detail and I have a class that have 2 fields and geters and seters.How to fill the table with java bean?

My code

```
public class Table {

    private String gigo;
    private String bibe;

    public Table() {
    }

    public Table(String gigo, String bibe) {
        this.gigo = gigo;
        this.bibe = bibe;
    }

    public String getBibe() {
        return bibe;
    }

    public String getGigo() {
        return gigo;
    }

    public void setBibe(String bibe) {
        this.bibe = bibe;
    }

    public void setGigo(String gigo) {
        this.gigo = gigo;
    }



}
```

The tablemaker

```
public class TableMaker {

        public ArrayList<Table> setTableBeanList() {
        ArrayList<Table> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<>();

        dataBeanList.add(produce("test1", "test2"));
                return dataBeanList;
    }

    private Table produce(String name, String occupation) {
        Table TableBean = new Table();

                TableBean.setBibe(name);
                TableBean.setGigo(occupation);

        return TableBean;
    }

}
```

the report:

```
InputStream inputStream=Reporter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("report2.jasper");    
TableMaker test = new TableMaker();
ArrayList<Table> tablelist = test.setTableBeanList();         
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tablelist);
Map parameters = new HashMap();   
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(inputStream);
 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters,beanColDataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "D://timer2.pdf");
```

In the table i get null, why?How to fill the table properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try generate two elements in dataBeanList. How many records display report in this case?

Comment: I add two dataBeanList.add(produce("test1", "test2")); and get two tables with null

Comment: I don't understand. Two tables or two records? Show jrxml. Which version of jasper?

Answer (score -1):

Once you have your Java Bean working, **you need to add your Variable manually in the Jasper Report.** Once done, you can use these Java Bean getters as variables along with other datasource variables by simply dragging them on the report from the OUTLINE WINDOW.

Else you can also create a custom table using the Table wizard and all these variables will be accessible.

Comment: Author don't ask about variables. He use fields, which values obtained from getters

Comment: Yes, so for these fields, he can create parameters manually instead of Variables which can be used in the Jasper Report.